# binary search tree updating

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I am developing an application which needs to store the values in a binary search tree. It is some what similar to the application which implements textpad by storing each line as a value with some key. If a line is deleted, keys for lines after that are updated in O(n). I am able to achieve O(n) time in my application by considering a parameter similar to line number(in the example) as the key.

Is there a way to achieve O(log n) time by choosing some other key?

Answer (score 1):

If you need guaranteed `O(logN)` peformance from a binary tree you should use a self-balanced version e.g. [Splay Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) or [Red black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)

Answer (score 1):

If your requirements are to Insert/Update, Delete and Search, then try `Hash Table` with good hash function.  Many languages provides hash table implementations `unordered_map` in C++, `dict` in python, `{}` in javascript... Oh btw, You can write one yourself.

Also you can try some balanced bst for `O(log(n))` like Red-Black trees, avl trees, 2-3 trees.